# CSS to Display Image and Text on a Image

Tags: html, css

I have a header Image width of 100% and height of 120px on top of the Page.

I want to display Header text on that Header Image in the center.

I want to display another small Image on the right hand side of the header Image of 80% of the height of the header image leaving 10% on top and bottom.

I want to leave 5px on the right hand side of the small Image also. So that Small Image will look as it is on the header Image.

What is CSS to get this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post your current code. Also consider making a JSFiddle with it

Answer (score 0):

I'd set the image as background via CSS, then I'd position the other elements, the text you want in the center and the other small image to the right, via two separate HTML absolute positioning Divs tags. Make certain the CSS ID tag is set to relative...

```
<div  style="width: 200px; height: 23px; position: absolute; right: 12px; top: 399px;" align="center">YOUR IMAGE OR TEXT HERE</div>
```

Set the parameters to your needs, of course.

Comment: Hi,I am displaying the background Image Using Repeater. I want to know the dynamic CSS that will work for this scenario.